# ¿Es posible dar un orden específico al agrumento fill de la opción aes de ggplot() de la libreria ggplot2 en R?

Tags: r

Estoy intentando hacer un gráfico de barras en R, la duda va más enfocada a la opción fill, lo que yo quiero es que me dé un orden específico al momento de utilizar fill, esto es:

Al utilizar fill la gráfica me da la leyenda con las etiquetas en el siguiente orden : a,b,c y yo quisiera que las etiquetas las ponga de la siguiente forma
b,a,c ¿Es posible hacer eso?

```
library(ggplot2)
ventas<-Ventas<-c((runif(9,0,1)*100))
Meses<-c(rep("Diciembre 2018",3),rep("Noviembre 2019",3),rep("Diciembre 2019",3))
Productos<-c(rep(c("Sabritas","Coca Cola","Galletas"),3))
df<-data.frame(Ventas,Productos,Meses)
ggplot(df,mapping=aes(x=Productos,y=Ventas,fill=Meses))+geom_bar(stat = "Identity",position = position_dodge())
```

Me gustaría que en la gráfica que estoy obteniendo las barras tengan el siguiente orden: Diciembre 2018, Noviembre 2019, Diciembre 2019 introducir

[image: Posible gráfica resultante del código]

ya encontré la solución, la cual es la siguiente:

```
    ventas<-Ventas<-c((runif(9,0,1)*100))
    Meses2<-c("Diciembre 2018","Noviembre 2019","Diciembre 2019")
    Meses<-c(rep(Meses2[1],3),rep(Meses2[2],3),rep(Meses2[3],3))
    Productos<-c(rep(c("Sabritas","Coca Cola","Galletas"),3))
    df<-data.frame(Ventas,Productos,Meses)
    ggplot(df,mapping=aes(x=Productos,y=Ventas,fill=factor(Meses,level = Meses2)))+geom_bar(stat = "Identity",position = position_dodge())
```

y con ese cambio solucione el orden. 
Gracias por la atención.

Comment: Bienvenido Alberto Lara a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Respondiendo a tu pregunta: Si es posible, pero para responderte mejor deberíamos compartir minímamente el código y datos de lo que estás haciendo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa la función `reorder` del package `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
ventas<-Ventas<-c((runif(9,0,1)*100))
Meses<-c(rep("Diciembre 2018",3),rep("Noviembre 2019",3),rep("Diciembre 2019",3))
Productos<-c(rep(c("Sabritas","Coca Cola","Galletas"),3))
df <- data.frame(Ventas,Productos,Meses)

ggplot(df, 
    mapping=aes( x=reorder(Productos, Meses),
    y=Ventas,fill=Meses)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "Identity",position = position_dodge())
```